# firebase cloud messaging does not work from server

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notification from my server to my web application and it works on my local project but when I push that, firebase does not work

```
try {
     FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
          .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
               new ClassPathResource("myapp-3c3c3-firebase-adminsdk-emn30-37a5092d63.json").getInputStream()))
           .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp-3c3c3.firebaseio.com")
           .build();
            
     FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
      setInitialized();
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```

the exception message:

```
Unknown error while making a remote service call: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must     be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}
```

the json config file is on resources of module on spring project

```
Message message = Message.builder()             
     .setNotification(Notification.builder().setTitle(title).setBody(contents).build())
      .setToken(token)
       .build();
return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Comment: check your cloud functions log, there is most likely errors

Comment: there is no log there

Comment: `Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was with the server time which was 10 minutes after the real time